# ModelBuilder symbology not showing/applied to layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, symbology

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I am executing this model outside of the ModelBuilder and it works almost as intended. I have checked and the model executes without a single warning message.

[image: Full Model]

The final output layer currently copies the symbology of the previous layer present in the map, which it shouldn't do.
Both output nodes [Copy Features] and  [Apply Symbology From Layer] are defined as "Parameter" and "Add to Display". I get the same output when only [Apply Symbology From Layer] has these definitions.

I don't think that the symbology layer is the issue because it works just fine when doing [Apply Symbology From Layer] "normally".

Is there perhaps a way to force a symbology update to this final output layer in the ModelBuilder ?

Answer (score 0):

So while I was writing the initial post I tried a workaround where I duplicated the [Apply Symbology From Layer] node. Not really the best solution, but a solution nonetheless. I am still curious to see if there is a better solution.

[image: Duplicated Node]